# ASP.NET SQLDataSource content sorting

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, sqldatasource

I created sql procedure, which returns table from database, where records are in some, defined order. But, when I execute this procedure and using `sqldatasource` and show results in `GridView`, rows, aren't in the same order as it should be. I checked in SQL Management Studio, and sql procedure works fine. Here is code, how I execute procedure :

```
ds.SelectCommand = "EXEC MyProcedure";
TableGridView.DataSource = ds.Select(new DataSourceSelectArguments());
TableGridView.DataBind();
```

ds is `SqlDataSource` created using `<asp:SqlDataSource .../>`

Answer (score 1):

I would make sure that my SQL in my procedure has an ORDER BY to ensure that it will always sort initially the way you want.

```
SELECT * FROM Products ORDER BY ProductName
```

If you are still seeing your data come up in the incorrect order in your GridView, try setting it to not allow sorting to see if the control is changing the order.

```
TableGridView.AllowSorting = False;
```